# How to answer with (y,Y OR n,N) on math expression with random num and operators

Tags: java

The question: is n1>n2 OR n1<n2
The answer: y,Y OR n,N
The num + operators must be random.
If the user wrong he can try again - one more time.
So far I get to that point but Im stuck.
I need help with my code, or another way that will be easier for me to answer that.

```
public static void code1() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random r = new Random();

        int n1 = r.nextInt(10) + 1;
        int n2 = r.nextInt(10) + 1;

        int max = Math.max(n1, n2);
        int min = Math.min(n1, n2);

        boolean biggerThan = n1 % 2 == 0; //if this value is true it will print >
        boolean smallerThan = n1 % 2 !=0;
        System.out.print(n1);
        if (biggerThan)
            System.out.print(">");
        if (smallerThan)
            System.out.print("<");

        System.out.println(n2);

        char answer = s.next().charAt(0);
            if(answer=='y'||answer=='Y'){
                if(biggerThan) {
                    if (((max = n1) > (min = n2)))
                        System.out.println("Well done");

                   else if (((min = n1) > (max = n2))) //
                        System.out.println("Wrong answer");
                }
                if(smallerThan){
                    if (((max = n1) < (min = n2)))
                        System.out.println("Wrong answer");

                    else if (((min = n1) < (max = n2))) //
                        System.out.println("Well done");
                }
            }
```

Comment: `while (true) { <your code> }` and add `break;` after printing "Well done"?

Comment: That doesnt work, the break will limit the next commands